# About zero's of $f(s) = \sum_n p(n) n^{-s} = 1 + 2\cdot2^{-s}+ 3\cdot3^{-s}+ 5\cdot5^{-s}+\dots$

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, roots, zeta-functions

Let $f(s)$ be a somewhat zeta like function defined on the complex plane as :

$$f(s) = \sum_n p(n) n^{-s}= 1 + 2\cdot2^{-s}+ 3\cdot3^{-s} + 5\cdot4^{-s} + 7\cdot5^{-s} + \dots$$

where the coefficients $p(n)$ are the noncomposite numbers ( $1$ and the primes )

Consider solving $f(s)=0$.

It appears all but a finite amount of zero's have $\Re s\leq 2$.

Also it appears infinitely many zero's get arbitrary close to the line $\Re s=2$.

Is that true and how to prove or disprove those assumed properties ?

Comment: Please Dirichlet series are in $n^{-s}$ not $n^s$

Comment: @reuns done it !

Comment: "It appears..." How do you know? The chances that this is a question for which a sensible answer is available are very low, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Well the primes grow like $n ln(n)$ so that explains a bit. It resembles the PNT That is stated as no zero’s beyond RE(s) = 1.

Comment: What bit? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Also i did use a program to check for it. The “ all but a finite “ is a 1 digit number …

Comment: Notice how this $p(n) n ^{-s}$ is close to $ln(n) n^{-s+1}$ so my $ Re(s) = 2 $it is the analogue of $Re(s)=1$ for the Riemann zeta or Its derivative…. Unfortunaly we might not have a product form here

Comment: Why are you even talking about $\Re s\leq2$? Did you prove that $f(s)$ is continuable there?

Comment: @metamorphy hmm no I did not, but I think it does. I used truncated sums so I got no pole. I see no reason for singularities and truncated plots did not suggest them.

Comment: @metamorphy another reason is that the full domain of analytic requires the range of the full complex plane, but it appeared not that Way for that halfplane.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @metamorphy